# Examples of degrees of freedom

Tags: degrees-of-freedom

The idea of degrees of freedom is pretty well sunk into my head, but I was wondering could someone perhaps give me few easy examples on how one would determine the number of degrees of freedom?

For example: Lets say that we have a sample of $n$ observations $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ following some distribution.

Could someone come up artificial examples of different number of degrees of freedom with this sample, say: examples where degrees of freedom are:

$$\text{degrees of freedom} = n$$
$$\text{degrees of freedom} = n-1$$
$$\text{degrees of freedom} = n-2$$
$$\text{degrees of freedom} = n-3$$

This would help get a grasp on, how one would determine the actual number of degrees of freedom. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/894/31152

This answer helped me when I was thinking about degrees of freedom